# Corda Notary Cluster in Open Source

Tags: corda

Is it possible to configure/use a Notary Cluster in Open Source version? Or is it available only in R3 Corda (former Enterprise)?

Comment: I'd recommend you checkout the notary Demo

Answer (score 1):

There is notary Demo which may help you out in here.
Link:
https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo
It will just help get your head around it.